# How can I check from a Java class that an application has consumed a message?

Tags: java, testing, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

There is an application that makes some change on database after it has consumed a kafka event, but instead of check the effects on database ì, I would know if there is a way to check programmatically when the message has been consumed (without use the command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I've found this solution:

I create programmatically a KafkaConsumer with the same group.id of the consumer I want to test, then I use the "committed" method to get the latest committed offset for the partition-topic-group of interest.

It's not optimal and later i try to get more low level, but it gets work done.

Answer (score 3):

If You want API support you can use the below mentioned links :

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

[KafkaConsumerOffsets](https://www.ctheu.com/2017/08/07/looking-at-kafka-s-consumers-offsets/)